# Class armor proficiency vs. armor proficiency feats

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, armor, blood-hunter

Question being raised due to the [Blood Hunter](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/170777/Blood-Hunter-Class)'s armor proficiency, which has light + medium armor but no shields.

My question is: If a class already has proficiency for something built-in, can they still take the feat for it? i.e. Could a Blood Hunter take Moderately Armored and end up with shield proficiency?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, quite simply because nothing says you cannot. The rules for feats say you can (generally) only take each once, but the blood hunter doesn’t have the Moderately Armored feat, it just has proficiency in medium armor. And the Moderately Armored feat doesn’t specify that it has a requirement of *not* already having medium armor proficiency.

You may be interested in [this related question about medium armor proficiency without shield proficiency](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53769/4563).